# How do I test code that uses `module.hot`?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

I'd like to test code that is of the form:

```js
if (module.hot) {
  // do some stuff
}
```

What's the best way to get `jest` to execute the code path? I saw [Test module.hot with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037032/test-module-hot-with-jest), but would like to avoid modifying the non-test code.